# How to password protect wifi?

Tags: router, passwords

Where do I setup the password of the linksys router?

[image]

ADMIN TAB

[image]

Comment: Does the router have WiFi at all? At least on the product spec page it doesn't mention it ...

Comment: Yes it does. I'm at my laptop using the wifi now.

Comment: You are talking about a Linksys router in your question, but the screenshots are from a Prolink router ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I googled it based on the model from your screenshot. Here's a pdf - look at page 163:

[PROLiNK H9200](http://www.prolink2u.com/downloads/pdf/manuals/manual_H9200.pdf)

Comment: I heard that Google is a good search engine... Joke :)

Comment: Ooh..I didn't think of that, I only googled Linksys WRT54G which is what is written on the router. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The option to set the password to control access to the **router** itself is probably on the "Admin" tab.

There doesn't seem to be a "Wifi" or "Wireless" tab. That's where the option to set the passcode or passphrase (depending on whether you've enabled WPA or WEP2 access) would be found.

Have you checked the "Bridging" or "Services" tabs?

Comment: I posted the admin tab screen shot just now. Do you know where I can change the password?

Comment: @Dian - what's on the "..ser Config" link? Just click links. As long as you don't click "Save" or "Reset" type links you won't change anything.

Comment: It's the user config, that screenshot is actually the user config page. I haven't found any link which asks for the password or anything, I'm still trying to find it. :(

Comment: @Dian - in that case check out the manual @QuiXilver found.